# Retrieve Related module Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, rest

I have 2 modules: Quotes and ProductBundles. The Quotes Module has a relationship ProductBundles. The name of the relationship is "product_bundle_quote".

In this relationship, Primary Module is Quotes and the Related Module is ProductBundles.

I want to retrieve the associated Quote given by ProductBundle. How can I achieve this on my HTTP calls on Postman?

First I tried to get Quotes that also include ProductBundles using:

```
POST: {{sugarURL}}/rest/v10/Quotes/filter

Body:
{
  "filter": [
    {
      "fields": "product_bundle_quote"
    }
  ]
}
```

This says Unknown field fields.

I'm going through the SUGAR API docs, but no luck so fa.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

```
GET {{sugarURL}}/rest/v10/ProductBundles/{{productbundleID}}/link/quotes
```

This returns all linked quotes of the specified product bundle, in an array.
(For a one-to-many rel, there will usually be exactly one or no record in the returned array)

Go to `{{sugarURl}}/rest/v10/help` -> `GET /<module>/:record/link/:link_name` in your web browser for more info. Note that all params are optional.

Note:
The `/link/` api expects the name of the `link`-type field, **not** the relationship name.
E.g. the relationship `product_bundles_quote` is represented by the link-field `quotes` in Product Bundles and by the link-field `product_bundles` in Quotes. Check the respective module's metadata if not sure about the field names of a certain relationship.
The same is true for the `fields` param, it expects the link-field name. Also `fields` should *not* be inside `filter`, but a separate *array* on the same level as `filter`.